# ぬ in place of の

Tags: particles, dialects

The lyrics of the [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uin_Dutg3FU) go like this:

> 教科書に書いてある事だけじゃわからない
>
> 大切な物がきっとここにあるはずさ
>
> それが**島人ぬ宝**

Why is ぬ used where の is expected? It this something Okinawan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia 沖縄方言](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B2%96%E7%B8%84%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E):

> #### 日本語共通語との対応関係
>
> 琉球語沖縄方言（琉球語派沖縄語）では、**日本語のオ段母音がuに**、エ段母音がiに対応している。そのため殆どの行で日本語のオ段とウ段、エ段とイ段は統合している。
>
> #### 助詞
>
> 格助詞のガとヌには、主格と属格（連体格）の両方の用法がある。現代日本語では「が」は主格、「の」は連体格であり、「が」の連体格や「の」の主格の用法は使わなくなっている。ガとヌには使い分けがあり、例えば首里方言では、人が主語の場合はガ、人以外が主語の場合はヌを使い、**連体格の場合、尊敬すべき者には格助詞を使わず、尊敬されない者にはヌを使う**などの区別がある。

So yes, ぬ in Okinawan is basically the same word as の, although it has some grammar rules that are different from those of mainland Japanese. Some pages say this type of ぬ is almost dead now, and, for the most part, the lyrics are written in standard Japanese. So this may be seen as an archaism.